# Problems with Git Commit

Tags: git

When I put off into `git commit` then I end up with this answer:

```
***Please tell me who you are.
Run:
   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
   git config --global user.name "Your name"

Omit --global to set the name only in this repository.
fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (Got username@computername.<none>)
```

But when I run either of the options above, then run `git commit` I still end up with the above message. I ran them with just plain old `git commit` from `cmd.exe`. My OS is Windows Vista. Also my `.gitconfig` is in `C:\Users\<username>\.gitconfig`.

Comment: how did you enter the commands? what is your OS?

Comment: Windows Vista - as he says in the question.

Comment: Try without --global params in your project dir.

Comment: Oh my gosh, you're still using Vista! You have my sympathies.

Comment: Please update your question with information on how you have Git installed, and which version you're using (msysgit, or Cygwin, or something else)? Also, you can find information on where your user `.gitconfig` file might be installed at the [official Linux Kernel Git documentation for git-config(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html#FILES).

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're using `cmd.exe` instead of the more common console programs that people use with Git, like msysgit bash, Cygwin mintty, and PoshGit Power Shell?

Comment: I have msysgit bash, but I don't know how to use `bash`.

Answer (score 2):

If running the commands does not work—for whatever reason—then you can also enter the information yourself by editing the `.gitconfig` file.

Open up `C:\Users\<username>\.gitconfig` in a texteditor (not notepad.exe though), and add the following lines (with your information of course):

```
[user]
    name = Your Name
    email = Your.Name@domain.tld
```

If a `[user]` section is already in the file, try to merge it correctly so it isn’t duplicated.

Comment: While just directly going an editing the config file is fine, it would be nice to figure out what he couldn't just simply do it from the command line as well. Also, you're assuming that the user's `.gitconfig` file is located at `C:\Users\<username>\.gitconfig`. This is not necessarily the case for all installations of Git on Windows. A default Cygwin installation of Git will place the file under `C:\<cygwin directory>\home\<user>`.

Comment: @Cupcake Fair point. Though it’s impossible to say this without further information from OP… :/

Comment: Mine is on `C:\Users\<username>\.gitconfig`.

Answer (score 0):

If your `.gitconfig` file is located in a directory that is protected by User Access Control (UAC), then you might need to run your console with elevated permissions (as Administrator) in order to be able to modify/write to that file using

```
git config --global <setting>=<value>
```

For example, if you're using a Cygwin installation of Git, and you have your `cygwin` folder installed under

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\cygwin\
```

then your `.gitconfig` file might be located at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\cygwin\home\<username>\.gitconfig
```

in which case you might need elevated permissions since it's located under a UAC protected folder, `C:\Program Files (x86)\`.

Beware, however, that some other installations of Git will change the location of a Cygwin drive default home directory (there's a Stack Overflow answer floating around somewhere about it, I'll link to it if I find it again). I've had the experience of installing either GitHub for Windows or msysgit, and then installing Cygwin, and either GitHub for Windows or msysgit set an environment variable that changed what Cygwin would use for a home directory to

```
C:\Users\<username>\
```

instead of

```
<cygwin directory path>\home\<username>\
```

Comment: Downvoters, please explain why you downvoted. I don't see anything obviously wrong with my answer. If there is anything wrong, I will edit my answer to correct it.

Comment: The `.gitconfig` is stored in `C:\Users\<username>\.gitconfig` which is part of the user account and as such always writable (for the current user) without elevated permissions. (Didn’t downvote though)

Comment: @poke this assumes that the user's `.gitconfig` is located at `C:\Users\<username>\.gitconfig`, like if he used a default msysgit install. But what if the original poster is using something like Cygwin, and has it installed somewhere under `Program Files`? Then depending on how he configured Cygwin, his home directory might be in a subfolder somewhere in `Program Files`.

Comment: A default Cygwin installation in that case would place his home directory in `C:\Program Files\cygwin\home\<user>`, and since it's under `Program Files`, the original poster might need elevated permissions to modify files in it, including a `.gitconfig` file.

Comment: Yes my `.gitconfig` is in `C:\Users\<username>\.gitconfig`.